# MIN() and MAX() in Swift and converting Int to CGFloat

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm getting some errors with the following methods:

1) How do I `return screenHeight / cellCount` as a `CGFLoat` for the first method?

2) How do I use the equivalent of ObjC's MIN() and MAX() in the second method?

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> CGFloat {
    var cellCount = Int(self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(indexPath.section))

    return screenHeight / cellCount as CGFloat
}

// #pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate

func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let height = CGFloat(scrollView.bounds.size.height)
    let position = CGFloat(MAX(scrollView.contentOffset.y, 0.0))

    let percent = CGFloat(MIN(position / height, 1.0))
    blurredImageView.alpha = percent
}
```

Comment: Though is commented below, you can just write min or max, in lowercase. That's all for Swift.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

1: You can't downcast from Int to CGFloat. You have to initialize a CGFloat with the Int as input.

```
return CGFloat(screenHeight) / CGFloat(cellCount)
```

2: Use the min and max functions defined by the standard library. They're defined as follows:

```
func min<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T
func max<T : Comparable>(x: T, y: T, rest: T...) -> T
```

Usage is as follows.

```
let lower = min(17, 42) // 17
let upper = max(17, 42) // 42
```

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted your answer as it's straightforward and also for providing the full `min()` `max()` function(s). I almost had it right had I just converted `MIN()` `MAX()` to lowercase.

Answer (score 10):

If you're using Swift 3, `max()` and `min()` are now called on the sequence (i.e., collection) instead of passing in arguments:

`let heights = [5, 6]
let max = heights.max() // -> 6
let min = heights.min() // -> 5`

Answer (score 3):

You can just use min() and max() - they're built-in.

If you wanted to roll your own (why? - maybe to extend it) you would use something like

```
func myMin <T : Comparable> (a: T, b: T) -> T {
    if a > b {
        return b
    }
    return a
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to explicitly convert `cellCount` to `CGFloat`, since Swift doesn't do automatic type conversion between integers and floats:

```
return screenHeight / CGFloat(cellCount)
```

`min` and `max` functions are defined by the standard library.